# React Native: Is it possible to create floating chat heads like facebook messenger?

Tags: android, react-native

Is it possible to create floating chat heads like facebook messenger by using react native?

Comment: This is how you create "floating chat heads" in normal java (inside AND outside of your app) on Android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244548/changing-layoutparams-of-always-visible-chat-heads-to-not-always-visible/47623784#47623784). Because react-native uses JavaScript (inside it's own sandbox), I don't think you can produce "chat-heads" outside of your app.

Answer (score 15):

Without native coding, you can just make them show inside of your app, here is fine [example](https://gist.github.com/garrettmac/9d10c67c17b2eec4f14880dde927a449), it basically extends [react-native-interactible](https://github.com/wix/react-native-interactable/blob/master/real-life-example/src/ChatHeads.js) example.

If you want them to stay when the app is closed, I am afraid that there is not some react native library at the moment (as far as I know) that can provide you that, just native code something like in this [article](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/create-chat-heads-like-facebook-messenger-32f7f1a62064).

Answer (score 3):

We implemented a library for this. You need to install it and follow the instructions in the [README](https://github.com/hybriteq/react-native-floating-bubble/blob/master/README.md).

Then:

```
import { showFloatingBubble, hideFloatingBubble, requestPermission } from "react-native-floating-bubble"

// Show Floating Bubble
showFloatingBubble().then(() => console.log("Floating Bubble Added"));
```