# What is the best approach to create a dragable floating buttons

Tags: android

On Samsung mobiles you can pin an application, to have it in a floating window, and can be minimized to a floating circled button / icon ... What is the best approach to accomplish this? Do I go for using Service that holds ImageView or do I go for the Floating Action Button (If it's possible to drag it around).

By any chance if there's an open source project that has this feature, could you please guide me to it.

Thank you

Comment: One approach  is to hack [this source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47244548/changing-layoutparams-of-always-visible-chat-heads-to-not-always-visible/47623784#47623784).

Comment: Thank you Jon, does Facebook has its apps (Facebook - Messenger) source code online available for developers?

Comment: Facebook do release SOME open source, but not ALL [example](https://github.com/fbsamples). I doubt you will find anything useful to you in this regard, but my first comment example is quite easy to implement.

Comment: Again thank you, the library mentioned in the other question seems sufficient to do what I require... As for FB source code for further learning.

Comment: Yes as you can see I hacked away at it to answer that question.